# Getting an error while trying to print

Tags: c#

I'm getting the following error while trying to print,

Error in Printing : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name : ptr

Can anyone help me on y this error keep coming.?
This issue started only after updating my printer drivers.

Comment: Could you give some more information? Where does the error come up?

Comment: If this is anything to do with your own code, you need to post the code. If it's just a problem with the printer, you should go to superuser.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the printer is not configured properly.

Some of the object for the printer is coming as `null` in the code and this null you are trying to `pass it as a non null able parameter`.

Better to check the printer object is configured properly.